# What is the origin of astronomical seasons beginning at equinoxes?

Tags: calendar

In some part of the world (like the US) seasons are defined as astronomical seasons with spring *starting* exactly at the equinox and ending exactly at midsummer. (Other countries use other definitions, like meteorological ones based on temperature, or just fuzzy definitions.)

Question: What is the origin of the use of astronomical seasons (in the western world), and possibly its name?

I can see that people celebrated equinoxes and the seasons in ancient times (in Rome and Greece; others might have used fewer or more - some indicate that the Vikings had two that weren't aligned with the equinoxes) and they studied astronomy and astrology.

However, that doesn't necessarily mean that the equinoxes were the start of the seasons - some seem to have the equinoxes as the middle (hence mid-summer), and other celebrations float around the equinoxes (like Easter), which seems odd if the equinox marked the start of something.

It could, of course, be that I totally misunderstand how they viewed the world.

The earliest *unambiguous* sign I could find was the French revolutionary calendar (but not in the earlier "Almanach des Honnêtes-gens" by Sylvain Maréchal).
The earliest *possible* sign would be the Babylonian tradition of astrology with star signs starting at the equinoxes (which we still use today), but it's unclear if the grouping of signs defined seasons, and if that is the origin that seems at odds with the name 'astronomical' - as astronomy as a word is more recent.

Added:
It seems one of my original assumptions were incorrect about the ancient world.

The four seasons weren't necessarily of equal length - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attic_calendar
had one lunisolar calendar roughly based on equinoxes, and **a sidereal calendar for activities such as farming**; where spring and autumn were shorter - and the seasons weren't the same everywhere but adapted to the local variations.

Such variations explain why it unclear if Demeter spent four or six months in the underworld.

Julius Caesar's Gallic War also seem to view seasons as varying with geography "During the short part of summer which remained, Caesar, although in these countries, as all Gaul lies towards the north, the winters are early,"

Comment: In England the period from Spring Equinox to Summer Solstice has traditionally been *low summer*, and from Mid-Summer to the Fall Equinox has been *High Summer*. hence the term *Mid Summer's Day* for the Solstice day itself. Then Spring precedes the Spring Equinox and fall follows the Fall Equinox. "*People*" have always used terms meaningful to their particular circumstance - but mass nation-wide media needs talking points - hence the attempt to "*standardize*" that which makes no sense to anyone.

Comment: I'm aware of the precession; and that means we now have two different systems for astrological signs - which muddies the water.

Comment: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season)

Comment: I have read that part of Wikipedia; it makes some claims that aren't backed up by sources as far as I can see.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I agree that it could be mass nation-wide media that "standardized" something for no clear reason (whereas farmers cared about planting and harvesting seasons); if so that hints at a recent origin.

Comment: The ancient [Babylonian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_calendar) started in [Nisan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisan), and the [Egyptian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_calendar) one in [Thout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thout), the equivalent of the Babylonian [Tishri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tishrei). The [Hebrew calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar) was inspired by both (Exodus 12:2; Leviticus 23:24), as was the story of [Noah's flood](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/revisions/39426/2).

Comment: @Lucian The Babylonian and Hebrew calendars are lunar-solar and the date of the equinoxes thus have vary almost a month between the years. For Egypt your source says that it has three seasons (not four), and the year wasn't synchronized  with the seasons at all.

Comment: @HansOlsson: You asked for the origins. These are the origins.

Comment: @Lucian But those origins don't explain how we got from a lunisolar calendar with months starting at a moon phase after the equinox to a solar calendar with months not starting at equinoxes and a season-definition based on the equinoxes.

Comment: @HansOlsson: Through Christianity, an offshoot of the aforementioned Judaism, the important moments of the sun were aligned with dates of the of the Roman Julian calendar, itself a small correction of the Egyptian one, which it replaced upon [conquest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_war_of_the_Roman_Republic). March 25 is obtained by counting back fifteen [Metonic cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle) from the first Easter of the [Diocletian era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_of_the_Martyrs), as already stated [here](http://history.stackexchange.com/revisions/46700/3).

Answer (score -1):

Since the variation of the weather during the year has a regular component depending on position of the Sun with respect to the ecliptic, one has to define seasons with respect to this position. Knowing the seasons is important for agriculture, and
there is little doubt that originally calendar was invented for the needs of agriculture. This was long before the invention of writing.

There are 4 conspicuous points on the Sun path: the 2 equinoxes (when the sun's path crosses the
ecliptic) and 2 solstices (when the Sun is most remote from the ecliptic). The days when these events occur is not difficult to determine by direct observation.

They define the boundaries of the 4 (astronomical) seasons, and one of them (which can be chosen arbitrarily among these 4) is natural to define as the beginning of the year.

Comment: It might be possible, but you don't provide sources indicating that people historically thought this way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attic_calendar#Sidereal_calendar says "Hesiod also uses the rising of Arcturus to mark the ending of winter and marks the start of Spring with the coming of the sparrows. The seasons were not viewed by Greeks as dividing the year into four even blocks but rather spring and autumn were shorter tail sections of the overarching seasons, summer and winter."

Comment: Even the idea of having four seasons was not universal.  The Ancient Egyptians divided their year into three seasons: *Akhet*, *Peret*, and *Shemu*.  That was also based on their agricultural year.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Naturally. In Egypt the seasons (for the purposes of agriculture) are different from those in Europe and in the rest of Middle East.

Comment: My point was that the idea of four seasons of equal length was not something that was universal in the ancient world, which looks to have been one of the original assumptions expressed in the question.  Equally, the Mayans seem to have recorded solstices and equinoxes, yet their agricultural year had only two seasons (rainy season & dry season).  Calendars for agriculture really don't need to align with equinoxes!

Comment: @semipaiscuba: yes, the seasons in different parts of the world are defined according to their climate, but once they are defined, they have to be tied to solstices/equinoxes if one wants to predict them. Something like "begin sowing such and such number of days after the spring equinox".

Comment: Actually, the idea that they need to be tied to solstices/equinoxes is also not universal.  Many societies, including the Ancient Egyptians & the Babylonians, have used Lunisolar calendars, which were essentially Lunar calendars with some additional Intercalation. Even today, Easter is calculated using a Lunisolar calendar, which is why the date isn't fixed relative to the equinox.  However, Easter always falls *at about the same time of year* every year, which is also all ancient farmers really needed to determine when deciding when to start sowing crops.

Comment: Since the Moon has no influence on the weather, using Lunar calendar for agriculture (if it indeed was the case anywhere, which I doubt) was a mistake. The oldest agricultural manual that I read is Hesiodes, Days and Works. It uses stars (which is OK) but never the Moon.

Comment: Egyptians also used a star (Sirius) to predict the flooding of Nile.

Comment: There is no need to doubt.  Plenty of papers have been published about the use of Lunar and Lunisolar calendars in Mesopotamia (See, for a recent example that isn't behind a paywall, [The Nonintercalated Lunar Calendar of the Middle Assyrian Period](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/pdfplus/10.5615/jcunestud.69.2017.0151) ).  Lunar cycles are far easier to observe, and were probably known long before  solstices/equinoxes were measured. That is why so many Lunar and [Lunisolar  calendars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunisolar_calendar) survived into the historic period.

Comment: Using Lunar calendar FOR AGRICULTURE? (There are also some other uses of calendar).

Comment: Yes, "*FOR AGRICULTURE*". The linked paper explicitly mentions tablets that record agricultural activities carried out in  Assyrian **Lunar** months.  It also points out the difficulties involved for modern Assyriologists in situating those months within the solar year.

Answer (score -1):

After some more research:

Astronomy has needed a strict definition of seasons at least since Callippus found that they were of different lengths (around 330 BC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callippus), as described in Ptolemy's Almagest.
(Also indicating that equinoxes and/or solstice weren't precisely known long before that.)

That seems to have co-existed with other definitions outside of astronomy.

For the name it may be influenced by the similar ones: 'astronomical year' (introduced in 1740 by Jacques Cassini) and 'astronomical day' (introduced in the British Navy in 1767, http://www.royalobservatorygreenwich.org/articles.php?article=1087 ).